# onclick get element from api and with how many row form input field by user

Tags: javascript, html, api

Simple this i need to display this api "randomuser.me/api/?results=10" i table this job done, but i need use fill how row you need to display on the table and get the data from api
ex : user put 10 get 10 row and display it on the table

```
  <H3>How Many Row You Need to Display Below ?</H3>
  <label for="fname">Please Enter Number (Max 100):</label>
  <input type="number" id="fname" name="fname" min="0" max="100"  />
  <input type="submit" value="Get Data" id="results" />
  
  <br>


  <!-- <div id="f5buddytable"></div> -->

</form>


<script>
 // https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10 to get 10 row

  var url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?";     
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
      var table =
        "<table border='1'><tr><th> User Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Contact</th></tr>";
      var tr = "";
      var tableend = "</table>";
      var name, email, phone;
      for (var i = 0; i < users.results.length; i++) {
        name =
          users.results[i]["name"]["title"] +
          " " +
          users.results[i]["name"]["first"];
        email = users.results[i]["email"];
        phone = users.results[i]["phone"];

        tr +=
          "<tr> <td>" +
          name +
          "</td> <td>" +
          email +
          "</td> <td>" +
          phone +
          "</td> </tr>";
      }
      var finaltable = table + tr + tableend;
      document.getElementById("f5buddytable").innerHTML = results + finaltable;
    } else {
      console.error(users);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

Like this i need thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6PbF.png)

Comment: So wrap this into a submit button click or form submit handler, and then read the current value from the input field, and append a URL parameter to your API URL accordingly ... where is the actual _problem_ with that?

Comment: how can i do that? pleases help me i am new on code thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fetch` to get data, and use `document.createElement()` & `append()` to create and add rows to the table.

Here's an example:

> explanation provided as comments

> also You may  dismiss the css part, i just added it to make it look better

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const getInput = document.getElementById("getInput");

const tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
const status = document.getElementById("status");

getInput.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // gets value from input field
  const count = input.value;
  // check if taken value is 1-100
  if (input.value !== "" && count >= 1 && count <= 100) {
    // cleares the table
    tbl.innerHTML = "";
    // sets status message
    status.innerHTML = "Loading...";
    // send request to server to get data
    fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=${count}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        results = data.results;
        // removes status message
        status.innerHTML = "";
        // creates table columns
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");
        ["Name", "Email", "Contact"].map((col) => {
          const th = document.createElement("th");
          th.innerText = col;
          tr.append(th);
        });
        tbl.append(tr);

        results.forEach((user) => {
          // creates <tr> (row) for each user
          const tr = document.createElement("tr");

          // creates <td> for [Name, Email, Contact] and values them with the taken values from server
          const nameHolder = document.createElement("td");
          nameHolder.innerText = `${user.name.title} ${user.name.first}`;
          const mailHolder = document.createElement("td");
          mailHolder.innerText = user.email;
          const contactHolder = document.createElement("td");
          contactHolder.innerText = user.cell;

          // appends generated <td> to our row
          tr.append(nameHolder, mailHolder, contactHolder);
          // finally appends the created row to the table
          tbl.append(tr);
        });
      });
  }
  // if taken value is not in range(1-100), clears input field and table
  else {
    alert("Entered number must be 1-100");
    input.value = "";
    tbl.innerHTML = "";
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%, rgba(90, 92, 106, 1) 0%, rgba(32, 45, 58, 1) 81.3%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 80vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#status {
  color: rgba(245, 116, 185, 1);
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#input {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
}

#getInput {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(64.5deg, rgba(245, 116, 185, 1) 14.7%, rgba(89, 97, 223, 1) 88.7%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

tr:not(tr:last-child) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>How Many Row You Need to Display Below ?</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <label for>Please Enter Number(Max 100):</label>
    <input id="input" type="number" placeholder="1-100" min="1" max="100" />
    <button id="getInput">Get</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span id="status"></span>
    <table id="tbl"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you Alireza and you make the code look better

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get you right, but I think you are asking for url parameter?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search
You can get this in JS using this.

```html
const queryString = window.location.search;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

const page_type = urlParams.get('results')

console.log(results);
```

Then you add to html?

```html
var newhtml = ""

for(var i=0; i<results; i++){
  newhtml += <div>SOME DIV</div>

}

document.getElementById("container").innerHtml = newhtml;
```

I can't post comment so I post answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <h3>How Many Row You Need to Display Below ?</h3>
    <label for="fname">Please Enter Number (Max 100):</label>
    <input type="number" id="fname" name="fname" min="0" max="100" />

    <input type="submit" value="Get Data" id="results" />

    <br />

    <div id="f5buddytable"></div>
</form>

<script>
    const queryString = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).entries());
    var numberOfRecords = queryString.fname;
    var url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=' + numberOfRecords;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == '200') {
            var table = "<table border='1'><tr><th> User Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Contact</th></tr>";
            var tr = '';
            var tableend = '</table>';
            var name, email, phone;
            for (var i = 0; i < users.results.length; i++) {
                name = users.results[i]['name']['title'] + ' ' + users.results[i]['name']['first'];
                email = users.results[i]['email'];
                phone = users.results[i]['phone'];

                tr += '<tr> <td>' + name + '</td> <td>' + email + '</td> <td>' + phone + '</td> </tr>';
            }
            var finaltable = table + tr + tableend;
            document.getElementById('f5buddytable').innerHTML = finaltable; //REMOVED results, it was referencing the input submit
        } else {
            console.error(users);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I remove this [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, what do you want to remove?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/KLbxj3Gb7dY7oGpYA

Comment: solved, i edited my answer and commented the part

Answer (score -1):

just wrap `xhr` code into function and call it on any button on submit.
i just add this snippet for you.
this snippet not work in below editor, try on your screen.

```js
function getData(results) {
  // https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10 to get 10 row
  var url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?";
  if (results) {
    url += 'results=' + results
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
      var table =
        "<table border='1'><tr><th> User Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Contact</th></tr>";
      var tr = "";
      var tableend = "</table>";
      var name, email, phone;
      for (var i = 0; i < users.results.length; i++) {
        name =
          users.results[i]["name"]["title"] +
          " " +
          users.results[i]["name"]["first"];
        email = users.results[i]["email"];
        phone = users.results[i]["phone"];

        tr +=
          "<tr> <td>" +
          name +
          "</td> <td>" +
          email +
          "</td> <td>" +
          phone +
          "</td> </tr>";
      }
      var finaltable = table + tr + tableend;
      document.getElementById("f5buddytable").innerHTML = results + finaltable;
    } else {
      console.error(users);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
}

getData();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: olive;
      /* width: 100%; */
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javscript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>Test Sample</title>
  </head>

  <h1>Sample</h1>

  <body>
    <H3>How Many Row You Need to Display Below ?</H3>
  <label for="fname">Please Enter Number (Max 100):</label>
  <input type="number" id="fname" name="fname" min="0" max="100"  />
  <input type="submit" value="Get Data" id="results" onclick="getData(document.getElementById('fname').value)"/>
  
  <br>
  <div id="f5buddytable"></div>
  </body>

  </html>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you but the code not working with me any idea

Comment: i forget to add `<div id="f5buddytable"></div>` in html.